# LINQ Anonymous type - bypass Group By

Tags: c#, linq

I have LINQ sql (see below, thanks to [Cameron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2607840/cameron) ). I am trying to get a property (ItemCode) from class First without using that in Group by clause. 
How do I do that?

**Don't use First.ItemCode in group by but still want it in output by First.Begin, First.End order by decending.**

```
   public class First
    {
        public string Account;
        public DateTime Begin;
        public DateTime End;
        public decimal Amount;
        public string ItemCode;

    }

    public class Second
    {
        public string Account;
        public DateTime Begin;
        public DateTime End;
        public decimal Amount;
    }
                List<First> firstAccount = new List<First>();
                List<Second> secondAccount = new List<Second>();

                firstAccount.Add(new First()
                {
                    Account = "1234",
                    Begin = new DateTime(2014, 5, 13),
                    End = new DateTime(2014, 6, 12),
                    Amount = 9999,
                    ItemCode = "AAA"
                });

                firstAccount.Add(new First()
                {
                    Account = "1234",
                    Begin = new DateTime(2014, 6, 13),
                    End = new DateTime(2014, 7, 7),
                    Amount = 1000,
                    ItemCode = "AAA"
                });

                firstAccount.Add(new First()
                {
                    Account = "1234",
                    Begin = new DateTime(2014, 6, 13),
                    End = new DateTime(2014, 7, 14),
                    Amount = 0,
                    ItemCode = ""
                });

                firstAccount.Add(new First()
                {
                    Account = "1234",
                    Begin = new DateTime(2014, 7, 7),
                    End = new DateTime(2014, 7, 14),
                    Amount = 1000,
                    ItemCode = "BBB"
                });

                secondAccount.Add(new Second()
                {
                    Account = "1234",
                    Begin = new DateTime(2014, 5, 13),
                    End = new DateTime(2014, 6, 12),
                    Amount = 9999
                });

                secondAccount.Add(new Second()
                {
                    Account = "1234",
                    Begin = new DateTime(2014, 6, 13),
                    End = new DateTime(2014, 7, 14),
                    Amount = 2000
                });

var result = from account in (from first in firstAccount
                                join second in secondAccount
                                  on first.Account equals second.Account
                                where
                                  ((first.Begin >= second.Begin && first.Begin <= second.Begin) &&
                                   (first.End >= second.Begin && first.End <= second.End))
                                select new
                                {
                                  first.Account,
                                  second.Begin,
                                  second.End,
                                  first.Amount,
                                  first.ItemCode
                                })
               group account by new {account.Account, account.Begin, account.End }
               into groupedAccounts
               select new
               {
                 groupedAccounts.Key.Account,
                 groupedAccounts.Key.Begin,
                 groupedAccounts.Key.End,
                 Sum = groupedAccounts.Sum(a => a.Amount)
               };
```

Comment: Please put more effort into formatting your code - it's all over the place at the moment. Making the code rather smaller wouldn't hurt, either... just adding constructors to `First` and `Second` and using collection initializers would make it a lot smaller, and I suspect you don't really need *all* those fields to demonstrate the problem anyway.

Comment: If `ItemCode` is not in your group by clause you can't reference it after the group by because in any given grouped row there may be multiple different values for `ItemCode`

Comment: @JonSkeet It really depends on the person, some people want more details. Once I gave limited info and I got -ve points for that. Now I got -ve for giving more details. I think people should really focus on question/content rather than criticizing the post.

Comment: @BenRobinson Yes. You are correct. That's the reason I want most recent one in that group. I am trying to group
6/13/14-7/7/14, 6/13/14-7/14/14,7/7/14 -7/14/14 into one. In this case I want ItemCode from 7/7/14 -7/14/14.

Comment: Ideally, you should provide an example which is short (this isn't), complete (this isn't), and well-formatted (this isn't). It's about removing unnecessary clutter, while providing all the information which is important about the question, and making it as easy to read as possible.

Comment: "That's the reason I want most recent one in that group." - That's precisely the sort of information which needs to be in the question. It's not clear where you're trying to use ItemCode, either...

Comment: @JonSkeet Is this the best code (maybe not), because I made this is just for forums. Is this forum a code review platform (no). Code well formatted (maybe not), I used short-cur CTRL+K and it did the formatting for me (maybe there is a bug there). In my view, if I know the answer to a question, I will try to answer it or ask for more details other wise I will just walk away.

Comment: Happy to walk away now. Was hoping to help you ask better questions in the future, but if you're not interested in that, just don't expect as many answers as you would get if you put more effort in. Read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints if you *are* interested in asking better questions. (And no, Stack Overflow isn't a forum either.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to get the `itemcode` is to change the last `select`.
Add this line

```
Itemcode = String.Join(" ",groupedAccounts.Select(q=> q.ItemCode))
```

after `Sum = groupedAccounts.Sum(a => a.Amount),`

It should produce `itemcode`

```
foreach (var data in result)
{
   Console.WriteLine(data.Account + " " + data.Itemcode);                
}
```

Output

```
1234 AAA
1234 AAA
```

Comment: Not the solution I am looking for, but giving you +1 because at least you attempted to do something. :)

Comment: What solution are you looking for?

Comment: I tried to add the line (Itemcode = String.Join(" ",groupedAccounts.Select(q=> q.ItemCode))) you said after 'Sum=...', and it gives me an error AnonymousType#1' does not contain a definition for 'ItemCode' and no extension method 'ItemCode'

Comment: @CoolArchTek I copied your code and added this line. It worked well. Since you can access `a.amount`, `itemcode` should also be accessible as well. May be something else is interfering.